# Regular expression for limiting character not working

Tags: php, regex

I want to limit the number of "b" between 1 and 6, for which I'm using the following code:

```
<?php
$str="Big black books being kept in a black bag of a beautiful babe";
$pattern="/(b){1,6}/";
   if(!preg_match($pattern,$str,$matches))
 {
 echo "Please use six bs";
 }else
 {/*do nothing*/}
 print_r($matches);
 ?>
```

But It's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want 6 b's in the entire string, or 6 b's in a row?

Comment: @Wash I want 6 b's in the entire string. Not in a row like bbbbbb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through regex alone..

```
$str="Big black books being kept in a black bag of a beautiful babe";
$pattern="/^([^b]*b){1,6}[^b]*$/";
   if(!preg_match($pattern,$str,$matches))
 {
 echo "Please use upto six bs";
 }else
 {/*do nothing*/}
 print_r($matches);
```

and note that this must except atleast one single b. If you want to match also the line which don't have any single `b` then use `/^([^b]*b){0,6}[^b]*$/`

Add case-insensitive modifier `i` if you want to count also for capital `B`'s.

**Explanation:**

- `^` start of the line.
- `([^b]*b){1,6}` It matches (zero or more non-b characters and a `b`)(from 1 to 6 times). So this ensures that there must be character `b` exists min of 1 time and a max of 6 times.
- `[^b]*` Matches any char but not of `b`, zero or more times. This ensures that there are no more further `b` exists.
- `$` End of the line boundary..

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you Avinash Raj. But can you PLEASE explain a little bit on what this pattern translates to? I mean what does it mean?

Comment: `$str="Big black books being brought"; $pattern="/^([^b]*b){1,6}[^b]*$/";    if(!preg_match($pattern,$str,$matches))  {  echo "Please use upto six bs";  }else  {/*do nothing*/}  print_r($matches);`

Comment: use non-capturing group `^(?:[^b]*b){1,6}[^b]*$`

Comment: ^ start of the line. (? Makes the '(' optional. ':' what is this for?

Answer (score 0):

Try using match count.

```
<?php
    $str="Big black books being kept in a black bag of a beautiful babe";
    preg_match_all("/(b)/i",$str,$matches);
    if(isset($matches[1]) && count($matches[1]) > 6 )
    {
        echo "Please use six bs";
    }else
    {/*do nothing*/}
    print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: whats wrong with preg_match_all() ? why you want only preg_match() ?

Comment: Because I'm asked to do it with preg_match(). Its a task for me.

Comment: sorry friend, I don't know how to do it with preg_match(). I don't think it is possible.

Comment: @Vegeta it's possible. You can do anything with regex :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to count the number of Bs in the whole string while your regular expression counts them only in rows. i.e. "bbb" or just "b" would return a match.

Try using `substr_count` to achieve what I think you want. Here's an example.

```
<?php
    $str = "Big black books being kept in a black bag of a beautiful babe";
    if(substr_count($str, "b") > 6)
        echo "Six is the limit...";
    else
        echo "Doing nothing...";
?>
```

But of course, it won't really help if you want to see the found matches.

Comment: Thats a string function man, I want to limit the b using regex. Thanks for your efforts anyway.

Comment: user5237857 asked only to use preg_match().

Comment: @Vegeta I get it now that he told me. But I don't see any mention of using only regex in the question.